# Appending entire blend file into another?

Tags: append

Is there a way to append an entire blender file into another one?

I can add everything from each folder with box select but is there a faster way to import everything from a blend file?

Comment: Why don't you duplicate the file or save it under a different name, if both scene are supposed to be exactly the same?

Comment: You can add everything from each folder by opening that folder and pressing A once or twice to select that everything. Also you can append whole scene to get the same result.

Comment: Thanks guys that helped! Unfortunately duplicating the scene wouldn't help too much in this case because the blend file I am appending to has different contents than the one that I'm adding but appending the scene should work. : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html) and script your own append.

First recursively iterate through the .blend file using python and then call this function:

````py
from pathlib import Path


def append_from_blend_file(file_name, section_name, object_name):
    """ Append an object from existing blend file.

    :param file_name: Path to a blend file (e.g. actionlib.blend)
    :param section_name: Name of a section (e.g. Action)
    :param object_name: Name of an object to import. (e.g. WalkCycle)
    """
    path = Path(file_name)/section_name/object_name
    bpy.ops.wm.append(
        filepath=str(path),
        directory=str(path.parent),
        filename=str(path.name)
        )
```
````